# UPS Shipping as default one 1.7

Tags: shipping, ups

I am using Magento 1.7.x i had signup account for UPS, i had config correctly and working fine 
and i am getting the estimate shipping rate on cart page, and i can select best from there.

after choosing when i follow up after shipping address there comes a new shipping fixed Rate.
how can i get rid of that, and update with the shipping price i select earlier.
if Fixed Rate Enable is set to be NO i am not able to continue the shopping process.

Please help me.

Comment: In my cart page ESTIMATE SHIPPING AND TAX, UPS display shipping price, but checkout page UPS not showing. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento if you have disabled Fixed Rate then it is disabled for cart and checkout.  Assuming this is the case then the only way it will show in the checkout and not the cart is because of something that has been hardcoded in the checkout itself.

So if you are not seeing UPS in the checkout, and the address is the same as in the cart you need to check the codebase. If you have a checkout extension then switch off and see if get the same issue.

Standard Magento does not behave in the way you are describing.